# how can i replace string based on available string in xml

Tags: xml, shell, sed

I want to replace direction="Bidir" if in same node Url consists pB- in a xml.

I have tried

```
sed -i 's/Direction="unidir"/Direction="bidir"/g'
```

But i have to do it for each header where pB- is present in xml.

pri.xml contents-

```
<pri Bor="NO" Bpp="2" Direction="unidir" Hori="1200" Passes="12" Speed="40" Ver="1200" Url="pmode-jaguar9-12pU-40ips-2bpp-12x12dpi-12x12dpi_rampX1.xml" >

 <pri Bor="NO" Bpp="2" Direction="unidir" Hor="1200" Passes="12" Speed="40" Ver="1200" Url="pmode-jaguar9-12pB-40ips-2bpp-12x12dpi-12x12dpi_rampX1.xml" >
```

In second line, as you can see -12pB- is there, If pB- is present then i have to replace  Direction="bidir" in same line. As xml contains more than 100 lines.

I want xml should be like-

```
<pri Bor="NO" Bpp="2" Direction="unidir" Hori="1200" Passes="12" Speed="40" Ver="1200" Url="pmode-jaguar9-12pU-40ips-2bpp-12x12dpi-12x12dpi_rampX1.xml" >

 <pri Bor="NO" Bpp="2" Direction="bidir" Hor="1200" Passes="12" Speed="40" Ver="1200" Url="pmode-jaguar9-12pB-40ips-2bpp-12x12dpi-12x12dpi_rampX1.xml
```

Comment: `/pB-/s/Direction="unidir"/Direction="bidir"/g`?

Comment: `sed '/pB-/ s/Direction="unidir"/Direction="bidir"/g' xmlfile`

Answer (score 0):

sed "/pB-/s/Direction=\"unidir\"/Direction=\"bidir\"/" xmlFile

Answer (score 0):

If `pB-` always comes after `Direction=` as in your example:

```
sed 's/\(Direction="\)unidir\(".*pB-\)/\1bidir\2/'
```